# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).on("click", '.goToInvocationList', function(){
 <a href="#" id="create">Create slides</a>
});
```

this link is appended by ajax after loading the page 
and when i click this link it suppose to create the slides but it give me this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined.
but when i put the click event on a link not appended by javascript it work fine

```
$(document).on("click", '.go-invoice', function(){
  sildes_create();
  document.location.href='#invoce';

});
<div class="swiper-container">
 <div class="swiper-wrapper"></div>
 <span class="pagination"></span>
</div>

<script>
 function sildes_create(){
  count = 4;
  var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
      pagination: '.pagination',
      paginationClickable: true
    });

  for ( var i =0; i < 3; i++){
      mySwiper.createSlide('<div class="title" style="color:#000">Slide '+      (++count)+'</div>', 'swiper-slide #000-slide').insertAfter(0);
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: The first three lines of code you have shown on top of your post make no sense whatsoever, because you can not simply mix JavaScript and HTML code like that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the listener after the link is created:

```
   $(document).on("click", '.goToInvocationList', function(){
 $(something).append("<a href='#' id='create'>Create slides</a>")
  $('#create').on('click',function(){sildes_create();})
});
```